# finding and replacing special characters

Tags: c#, special-characters

Have some imported data which is leaving me with little invalid character symbols such as:

> Caf�

Just wondering what's the easiest way to find/replace these in string content?

Comment: Side note: you may instead want to fix you import process to handle non-ASCII characters correctly...

Comment: Perhaps you've got mismatched character encodings?

Comment: How do you know that those characters are "special"? How do you define "special"? Since this is an import process, you should find out the intention of the supplier of the data.

Comment: All valid comments thank you. Ideally would fix issue at the source within importer however not possible here as I'm just the recipient of the data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var newString = yourString.Replace("�", "");
```

where `yourString` is `Caf�`.

The special character can be used in the `Replace` statement. It should be as simple as that.

Comment: Not sure why I didn't think of that, was expecting something far more difficult. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This may help you. Results depend on what type of text you want to keep or remove...

[MSDN: How to: Strip Invalid Characters from a String](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/844skk0h%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

This will replace every nonalphanumeric characters(leaving punctuation intact):

```
string result = Regex.Replace(textBox1.Text, @"[^\w(\p{P}) ]+", "");
```

if you want only the letters and numbers and want to clear punctuation remove `(\p{P})` from the expression.